# Power Apps, user can only see and edit own records within app

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to edit my app in a way such that the user can only see and edit their own records.
I am trying to do this within the app itself and not the list.

As I list I am aware I can restrict permissions. But I am trying to do this in the app.

I need to restrict but `user().Email` as I use this in a "Created by" field.

How can I restrict my "BrowseScreen" by user id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a browser navigation screen to restrict screen viewing:  **If(User().Email="user1@email.com" Or "user2@email.com",TabNavigation,Filter(TabNavigation,ID=1 Or ID=2 Or ID=3))**

You would need to create a collection for the navigation.  Then have it appear in a gallery using the functions above.  Here is how to create a collection for this:  **ClearCollect(TabNavigation,{ID:1,Tab:"Product Name"},{ID:2,Tab:"Description"},{ID:3,Tab:"Filters"},{ID:4,Tab:"Pricing"})**

You can also filter the database you're using by the created by column.

And if you need a more advanced auto manged one.  You can create a user list and assign permissions like so.

| UserName | IsAdmin | IsSalesManager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | true | true |
| Tate | false | true |
| Dummy | false | false |

Then you can set your navigation to only show the nav options based on user permission.